# Php script encoding

Tags: php, character-encoding

i have an issue with a php script
I have a problem of encoding which my website does not recognize non english letters like Arabic and it appears strange characters like in the image below,  i tried to change the encoding in Database in phpMyAdmin to utf8_unicode_ci and the problem still there.
Anyone can help me to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Did you set the encoding of your driver? What driver is being used? Please add more details.

Comment: I am sorry but  how to do that? I dont have a big knowledge..

Comment: Depends on how you have PHP interacting with MySQL. With no code it is hard for us to assist.